# magento pagination with item per page not working

Tags: magento-1.9, product, pagination

I am trying to set the pagination with number of items per page. However, it is not working as expected.

Below is the code that I am using. However, every time it gave same output even when the value of `$page` is `1,2,3`

How can it be fixed ?

```
require_once '../app/Mage.php'; //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

if($_GET['page']){
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}else{
    $page = 1;
}

    echo $page;

    $category_id = $_GET['category_id']; 
    $catagory_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id); 
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    $collection->addCategoryFilter($catagory_model); //category filter
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1); //only enabled product
    $collection->addStoreFilter();  
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('id','name','small_image','price'))->setCurPage($page)->setPageSize(10); //add product attribute to be fetched


    if(!empty($collection)){
        foreach ($collection as $_product){
        //echo "<pre>".print_r($_product)."</pre>";
            $categoryapi['id']=$_product->getId();
            $categoryapi['name']=$_product->getName();
            $categoryapi['price']=$_product->getPrice();
            $categoryapi['image']=(string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(250, 250);
            $mcat[] = $categoryapi;
        }
    }
    echo $output = json_encode(array('data' => $mcat));
```